# Some of the Express public files are not accessible on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I run my Node.js app on localhost, I can access for example http://localhost:3000/css/dashboard.css

However, if I put a logo.png to the same directory and try http://localhost:3000/css/logo.png on my browser, I only get "Cannot GET /css/logo.png". I tried with several browsers.

In my app, the only reference to this is: expressapp.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
The files are in a public directory that is in the same directory with the main app. I am using Windows 10. The mentioned css file is much older than the png file, which I just added to the project.

I tried to google, but to no avail.

Comment: Is the logo.png inside the css folder, if not then you need to try http://localhost:3000/logo.png

Comment: What you describe should not be a problem so you're probably working with an incorrect assumption.  Let's check a few things.  The error says it is looking for `/css/logo.png` so your file should be in `public/css/logo.png`.  Is that where it is?  Are you 100% sure, you're looking at the actual `public` directory that the server is using?

Comment: The logo.png is inside the same css folder than dashboard.css, for testing purposes

Comment: Oh no... now I get it. I had a duplicate folder and somehow I accessed that one! I feel so silly, first of all for creating this duplicate in the first place, and second for not checking the path for myself. But the problem is now solved, thank you!!

Comment: The solution should be in an answer, not an edit to the question. And you indicate that the problem is solved by accepting the best answer, not by putting "Solved" in the title.

Comment: I understand, but what I am supposed to do in a situation where the problem is solved before there are any answers?

Comment: Oh right, I can use the answer button myself if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll move my comments into an answer here since it led to you finding the duplicate directory and we can wrap up this question...

What you describe should not be a problem so you're probably working with an incorrect assumption. Let's check a few things. The error says it is looking for `/css/logo.png` so your file should be in `public/css/logo.png`. Is that where it is?

Are you 100% sure, you're looking at the actual `public` directory that the server is using?   A not so uncommon mistake is to be madly editing files in a directory only to find out that it's a duplicate directory and is not the one the server is actually using.

Comment: Yes, I managed to use a duplicate folder, embarassing. But thank you a lot!